# Вызов перегруженной функции - Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

При вызове Func() заполняется buffer данными из сокета, после происходит их конвертация в класс Derived. Если после конвертаци вызвать функию Foo(), то происходит ошибка сигментации. Если создавать класс в стеке, то 
ошибка не происходит.

header file

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual char Foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Interface
{
public:
    char Foo() override
    {
        return val[0];
    }
    char val[10];
};
```

source file

```
boost::array<char, 8192> buffer;

void Func()
{
...
auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();

 std::memcpy(derived.get(), buffer.data(), sizeof(Derived));
 derived->Foo(); // Segmentation fault
...
}
```

Comment: что-то не видно метода get в вашем Derived

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, `derived` это `shared_ptr` а не `Derived`

Comment: а, точно, затупил

Comment: я так понимаю у вас в буффере символы char которые вы хотите записать в value, так?

Comment: `std::memcpy(derived->val, buffer.data(), sizeof derived->val)`

Comment: Я вообше не понимаю смысль: все пишется на языке C++, а вот копировать нужно на С

Comment: Я упростил класс Derived. В реальности он содержит несколько членов (тип int, double) и на каждый член функция для его возврата и установки. Как бы это POD структура

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а как можно тогда последовательность байт конверировать в структуру?

Comment: std::copy_n(buffer, sizeof(derived->val), derived->val);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, ИМХО, так лучше никогда не делать: записывать в объект побайтово какую-то последовательность байт, беря при этом указатель на начало объекта. Вот смотрите: если бы у вас это был простенький класс, то все бы работало как вы и ожидали (на сколько я могу судить), но вот вы унаследовались... Тоже вроде все должно работать, но у вот только у вас есть виртуальный метод - это все меняет. Можете сами убедится, для этого просто проверьте `sizeof`. Думаю вы удивитесь, тому что размер оказался больше, чем если бы не было виртуального методы. Дело в том, что компилятор должен как-то определять, какой метод дернуть, а если у вас есть виртуальные методы то как это сделать? Раз так, объект класса должен хранить указатель на таблицу функций (извиняюсь за неточность формулировки), которые он может и должен вызывать. Получается что вы переписываете указатель на эту таблицу, и объект обращается по невалидному указателю.

Вообщем: либо используйте метод для записи (собственно для чего и создавались классы), либо берите указатель именно на член класса, который нужно изменить и перезаписывайте исходя из его размера. Но второй вариант абсолютно претит принципам инкапсуляции.